Is there a way that I could use Arcgis Javascript SDK in Flutter?
I know it might be a dumb question but my company current tech stack is a bit weird where we are now have an app that has already built in Flutter(UI, etc.) but the challenge is Arcgis SDK is unlikely support flutter(I know there is a beta version to support it but that is not enough on what we want to use), so we decided to find a way to use JS SDK in flutter which something already built with very powerful features on it.
I've done a bit of research myself that how we could run JS in Flutter which:

calling a webview then embed .html(where JS SDK would be attached) - this could be a solution but I dont think we want to use it when term of complex calculation and logic come in
using Flutter_JS
But thing is JS SDK is relying on DOM to re-render the mapview whenever something has changed which something Flutter_JS and flutter itself cannot provide

Any glue on it will a big appreciated. Thanks guys!
